# select the TOP N rows from a table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

I am making some paging, and I need to make some query and get the result form defined slicing .
for example: I need to get all "top" rows in range 20n <  x < 40n etc.

```
SELECT * FROM Reflow  
WHERE ReflowProcessID = somenumber
ORDER BY ID DESC;
```

and now I need to make my sliding by column called ID .

Any suggestions how to so ?  I need to run my query on mysql, mssql, and oracle.

Comment: See the `LIMIT` clause http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html

Comment: Why the downvote? Why not put your comment in an answer? So many questions.

Comment: I'm fairly certain you won't get anything that works in all 3. You'd have to use `rownum` in Oracle.

Comment: @Ben: You are correct.  `FETCH FIRST # ROWS` is now ANSI, but DB2 IIRC is the only to currently support it.

Comment: did u try searching? (so many top-n pagination questions)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Assuming your page size is 20 record, and you wanna get page number 2, here is how you would do it:

SQL Server, Oracle:

```
SELECT *   -- <-- pick any columns here from your table, if you wanna exclude the RowNumber
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER OVER(ORDER BY ID DESC) RowNumber, * 
      FROM Reflow  
      WHERE ReflowProcessID = somenumber) t
WHERE RowNumber >= 20 AND RowNumber <= 40
```

MySQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Reflow  
WHERE ReflowProcessID = somenumber
ORDER BY ID DESC
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 20
```

Answer (score 27):

In MySql, you can get 10 rows starting from row 20 using:

```
SELECT * FROM Reflow  
WHERE ReflowProcessID = somenumber
ORDER BY ID DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20 --Equivalent to LIMIT 20, 10
```

Answer (score 6):

```
select * from table_name LIMIT 100
```

remember this only works with MYSQL

Answer (score 0):

you can also check this link

SELECT * FROM `master_question` WHERE 1 ORDER BY `question_id` ASC LIMIT 20

[for more detail click here](https://technicalblogs.co.in/question/how-to-display-top-20-rows-in-mysql/)

Answer (score 0):

From SQL Server 2012 you can use a native pagination in order to have semplicity and best performance:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#using-offset-and-fetch-to-limit-the-rows-returned

Your query become:

```
SELECT * FROM Reflow  
WHERE ReflowProcessID = somenumber
ORDER BY ID DESC;
OFFSET 20 ROWS  
FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY;
```