# Syntax error in retrieving data in c#.net

Tags: c#

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
con.Open();

OleDbCommand Comm1 = new OleDbCommand("select customer_id from tb_customer ORDER BY customer_id desc limit 1", con);

OleDbDataReader DR_customer = Comm1.ExecuteReader();
if (DR_customer.Read())
{
     textBox1.Text = DR_customer.GetValue(0).ToString();
}
```

Here I am trying to get the customer_id of the  last data entered. But I am getting syntax error in ORDER By clause.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `select top 1 customer_id` instead of `limit 1`? Limit is MySQL operator

Comment: @user what is 1 after limit in the query ?

Comment: but i want the last id.??

Comment: What database engine are you trying to connect to?

Comment: what about if OP is using mySQL?

Comment: You can check this answer from SO http://stackoverflow.com/a/9150494/823369

Comment: @user..your customerid should be identity..

Comment: I just saw 3 answer without even knowing which database OP's using. Wow..

Comment: that workrd...thanxx guyzzz

Answer (score 0):

You probably need `top` 1 instead of `limit` 1

```
new OleDbCommand("select top 1 customer_id from tb_customer ORDER BY customer_id desc", con);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Can you try this:**

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
con.Open();
OleDbCommand Comm1 = new OleDbCommand("select top 1  customer_id from tb_customer ORDER BY customer_id desc", con);
OleDbDataReader DR_customer = Comm1.ExecuteReader();
if (DR_customer.Read())
   textBox1.Text = DR_customer.GetValue(0).ToString();
```

Comment: instead of a textbox i want this value in  a variable and insert it in database...so how to get dat??

Answer (score 0):

Try this. `top 1`

```
select top 1 customer_id from tb_customer ORDER BY customer_id desc
```