# Find the TOP 400 rows having the most relationships

Tags: sql, oracle

The table looks like this

```
RELATION_ID  OBJECT_ID  RELATED_TO_OBJECT_ID    CLASS_ID    RELATION_TYPE_ID
7966561       910675              69305               7             1
7966562       910675              439104              7             1
```

The OBJECT_ID value `910675` has two related OBJECT_ID values in RELATED_TO_OBJECT_ID. I would like to find the top 400 OBJECT_IDs having the most  RELATED_TO_OBJECT_ID records and also `where CLASS_ID = 7 and RELATION_TYPE_ID = 1`.

Comment: Please edit the question and provide *relevant* sample data in the question (as a text table) and the desired output.

Comment: Just a note, `SELECT TOP 400` is [MySQL-specific](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9150494/1270789). See my answer below for the Oracle version.

Comment: @KenY-N From 12c onwards, Oracle supports the top-n row limiting feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a query along these lines, I think:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT OBJECT_ID, COUNT(*) as objectcount
    FROM table
    WHERE CLASS_ID = 7 AND RELATION_TYPE_ID = 1
    GROUP BY OBJECT_ID ORDER BY objectcount DESC)
 WHERE ROWNUM <= 400
```

The inner query creates a sorted table of OBJECT_IDs and the number of them that appear, then the outer query takes that result and limits it to the first 400 rows.

Note, I don't have an Oracle setup, but I referred to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498035/oracle-select-top-10-records).

Comment: i think you meant to use a <= in the last where clause

Comment: Thanks, [you are indeed correct](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/examples/first_rows.html)!

Comment: @KenY-N You need to `order by desc`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Oracle `12c`, you could use the new **Top-n row limiting** feature.

```
SELECT OBJECT_ID,
  COUNT(*) cnt
FROM table_name
WHERE CLASS_ID       = 7
AND RELATION_TYPE_ID = 1
GROUP BY OBJECT_ID
ORDER BY cnt DESC
FETCH FIRST 400 ROWS ONLY
```

If you want to include the duplicates, then add **WITH TIES**.

```
SELECT OBJECT_ID,
  COUNT(*) cnt
FROM table_name
WHERE CLASS_ID       = 7
AND RELATION_TYPE_ID = 1
GROUP BY OBJECT_ID
ORDER BY cnt DESC
FETCH FIRST 400 ROWS WITH TIES
```