# SQL - Select in Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, window-functions

I have the below working query from which I create a stacked-column-graph.

I now want to be able to filter top 10 [Prod_Model] with the highest count of [plugin ID] in total.

I tried to create an additional column summing [Plugin ID] (vulCnt) for each product disregarding [Risk].

My efforts to use `INNER JOIN` or `SELECT` inside the `SELECT` failed.

My working query:

```
select t.Prod_Model, 
    count(t.[Plugin ID]) as vulCnt, 
    (case t.Risk
        when 'Critical' then 1
        when 'High' then 2
        when 'Medium' then 3
        when 'Low' then 4
        Else 5
    End) As Rsk_Levl,
    t.Risk
from ************ t
where t.prod_model <>''
group by t.Prod_Model, t.Risk
order by t.Prod_Model
```

Result is -

```
|Prod_Model|vulCnt| Risk_Level| Risk    |
|procut 1  | 4    |    1      | Critical|
|procut 1  | 2    |    1      | High    |
|procut 1  | 6    |    1      | Medium  |
|procut 1  | 1    |    1      | Low     |
|procut 2  | 4    |    1      | Critical|
|procut 2  | 2    |    1      | High    |
|procut 2  | 6    |    1      | Medium  |
|procut 2  | 1    |    1      | Low     |
```

Now I need top##.

Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150370/select-the-top-n-rows-from-a-table

Comment: Don't understand. What do you mean by "database you are using" ?

Comment: May be you are using MySql, so you'll get always the first element in your rsk_level.

Comment: @Amos: are you sure you're using Sql Server?

Comment: @Amos I've deleted my answer because don't accomplish your question. Please fix your result set, because is not possible your rsk_level = 1 for every row

Comment: That output sure looks like MySQL

Comment: definitely SQL Server 2016

Comment: If you need to get the top 10 rows, use `top 10` in the query with an appropriate order by.
From what you have said *additional column summing [Plugin ID] (vulCnt)* I cannot get any idea how it would help you to achieve what you said. And so does, what `Inner Joins` or `select in select` failed

Comment: The current count is for the group product and vul|Cnt. This means that there are possibly four records for each product (Critical,H,L,M) . I want to select the top products by the sum of the product's vulCnt. I tried to create a fourth column with that total.

Comment: Please post some sample data, what your query is getting and the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want a window sum to generate the additional column. You can then use it this information to rank and limit:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        Prod_Model, 
        count([Plugin ID]) as vulCnt, 
        (case Risk
            when 'Critical' then 1
            when 'High' then 2
            when 'Medium' then 3
            when 'Low' then 4
            Else 5
        End) As Rsk_Levl,
        Risk,
        dense_rank() over(order by cnt desc) rn
    from (
        select t.*, count(*) over(partition by Prod_Model) cnt 
        from mytable t
        where prod_model <> ''
    ) t
    group by Prod_Model, Risk
) t
where rn <= 10
order by rn
```

Comment: Hi GMB and all, 
Your replies are very much appreciated.
A sample table looks like the following:

|Prod_Model | Plugin-ID | Risk       |
|Prod-1           |1234         |High       |
|Prod-1           |1236         |High       |
|Prod-1           |1212         |High       |
|Prod-1           |1288         |Critical    |
|Prod-1           |3411         |Critical    |
|Prod-1           |3214         |low         |
|Prod-1           |4444         |Medium  |
|Prod-1           |6567         |Low        |
|prod-2           | etc……

not the next comment too

Comment: In the query I created a risk-index because I wanted Risk to be ordered from
Critical to Low not in alphabetical order which places Low before Medium.
At this point I created a stacked bar graph. Everything OK up to now.
Now I want to be able to select the Prod_Models that have the highest risk-
Count in total.
Problem-
The query and the resulting graph are in Reporting Services. The top## will be a filter,
it needs to be in a single query.
Note the original query at the beginning of this discussion.
Thank you all,
Amos