# How sort a table based on age, and extract the top 2 user's address on mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this

```
create table users(
    user_id  int not null auto_increment,
    user_age date,
    user_address varchar(255),
    primary key(user_id)
    )
```

| user_id | user_age | user_address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2010-01-05 | 87 Polk St. Suite 5 |
| 2 | 2010-01-06 | Carrera 52 con Ave. Bolivar #65-98 Liano Largo |
| 3 | 2010-01-07 | Ave. 5 de Mayo Porlamar |
| 4 | 2010-01-08 | 89 Chiaroscuro Rd. |
| 5 | 2010-01-09 | Via Ludovico il Moro 22 |
| 6 | 2010-01-10 | Rue JosephBens 532 |
| 7 | 2011-01-05 | 43 rue St. Laurent |
| 8 | 2011-01-06 | Heerstr. 22 |
| 9 | 2011-01-07 | South House 300 Queensbridge |
| 10 | 2011-01-08 | Ing. Gustavo Moncaa 8585 Piso 20-A |
| 11 | 2011-01-09 | Obere Str. 57 |
| 12 | 2011-01-10 | Avda. de la Constitución 2222 |
| 13 | 2012-01-05 | Mataderos 2312 |
| 14 | 2012-01-06 | 120 Hanover Sq. |
| 15 | 2012-01-07 | Berguvsvägen 8 |
| 16 | 2012-01-08 | Forsterstr. 57 |

And I'd like my table to be like this:

| user_id | user_age | user_address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2010-01-05 | 87 Polk St. Suite 5 |
| 2 | 2010-01-06 | Carrera 52 con Ave. Bolivar #65-98 Liano Largo |
| 7 | 2011-01-05 | 43 rue St. Laurent |
| 8 | 2011-01-06 | Heerstr. 22 |
| 13 | 2012-01-05 | Mataderos 2312 |
| 14 | 2012-01-06 | 120 Hanover Sq. |

How can I make this happen with **group by** statement?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [select the TOP N rows from a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150370/select-the-top-n-rows-from-a-table)

Comment: `user_age=12` seems to have 6 records, from these 6 records, which 2 records do you want? Just 2 random ones?  Question says based on age, but all these records have same age...... (And do no say, "but I have show you which ones to select", I am asking HOW do you determine which 2 records to select)

Comment: Hi, sorry about the confusion, I've edited the column so it is clear. I want to select the top 2 records of each year. for example, I want 2 oldest people in year 2010 and also in year 2011 and 2012

Comment: Ok, then see: [select the TOP N rows from a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150370/select-the-top-n-rows-from-a-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `MySQL` supports windows function try:

```
with cte as 
    ( 
      SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by year(user_age) ORDER BY  user_age) row_num 
      FROM users  
      ) 
select user_id,user_age,user_address 
from cte
where row_num<=2;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3ceea7eab53ffd7f374636f5b7a450d1)

Comment: Hi :), I just want to know if it is possible to get the same result by using the "group by" statement? I've been trying it for some time now and I only got the result of the total number of users in the same year.

Comment: @Peifeng you don't need to use `group by`